# How do I index every Nth element of an array in Fortran?

Tags: arrays, indexing, fortran

I am struggling to index every nth element of an array in Fortran.

I have an array of 24 hours x 365 days x 91 steps of latitude, which I have declared as

```
 integer, dimension(1:24, 1:365, 1:91) :: my_array
```

I now would like to pick only every nth (lets say 10th) degree of latitude do reduce the resolution and write them no a second array

```
integer, dimension(1:24, 1:365, 1:10) :: my_new_array
```

I have no problem writing any 10 consecutive degrees of latitude to the new array e.g.

```
my_new_array = my_array(:,:,50:60)
```

but cant figure out how to do it with every nth element. In R or Matlab I would simply write a sequence from 1 to 91 by steps of 10, however that doesn't work for Fortran.

Comment: REPEAT UNTIL loop and add to a new array: http://www.tat.physik.uni-tuebingen.de/~kley/lehre/ftn77/tutorial/loops.html

Comment: Did you want my_array(:,:,::10) ?

Comment: you can do stepcontrol in a `do` loop... `do i =1,91,10`

Answer (score 2):

You can add a third element to the array slice:

```
my_new_array = my_array(:,:,1:91:10)
```

See section **6.5.3 Array elements and array sections** in the [Fortran Standard](http://www.j3-fortran.org/doc/year/10/10-007.pdf).

Since this is latitude, you might want to consider going from 0 to 90:

```
integer, dimension(1:24, 1:365, 0:90) :: my_array
```

And if you are doing the southern hemisphere, too:

```
integer, dimension(1:24, 1:365, -90:90) :: my_array
```